# Translation of Pentaho reports

Tags: python, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am trying to make a script for automatic transaltions of Pentaho 4 reports. What I found out is, that `*.prpt` files are just ZIPed XML files.

Sooo, *I have created python script that does either of following:*

**Upload phrases:**

1. Read files inside `*.prpt` file
2. Extract phrases from them
3. Put them into `*.po` file
4. Upload `*.po` file to OneSky

**Download translations:**

1. Download `*.po` file from OneSky
2. Uncompress original `*.prpt` file
3. Replace original phrases in files by translations
4. Compress new `*.prpt` file

While script seems to work perfectly and all steps are executed without any error, newly created `*.prpt` file can't be opened by "Pentaho Report Designer". There are many errors however I managed to find out, that it is probably not the case of my modifications.

By test, I have extracted report `*.prpt` file, and compress it again, without any modifications. Result? Same as with my modified file, report cannot be opened by Report Designer. Is here anybody who has experience with such modification of those files?

**Technical details:**

- MY OS: Linux debian
- language: python 2.7
- ZIP library: zipfile
- Pentaho bi-server version: 3.8.0
- Pentaho Report Designer version: 3.8.0

**Adding also ZIP files comparsion:**

*Original report file:*

```
Archive:  kpi2.prpt
Zip file size: 33203 bytes, number of entries: 50
-rw----     1.0 fat       41 b- stor 17-Feb-01 09:15 mimetype
-rw----     2.0 fat     5262 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 META-INF/manifest.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      733 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 meta.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      274 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat    26497 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 datadefinition.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      673 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 dataschema.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      266 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     6623 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 datasources/inline-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat    26649 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 datasources/scriptable-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1226 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 datasources/sql-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat    69826 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 layout.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      436 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 settings.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     4823 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      274 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport/content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      666 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport/datadefinition.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport/datasources/
-rw----     2.0 fat      133 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     6987 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport/layout.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1247 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport/styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      274 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport1/content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      664 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport1/datadefinition.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport1/datasources/
-rw----     2.0 fat      133 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport1/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     6992 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport1/layout.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1247 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport1/styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      274 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport2/content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      776 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport2/datadefinition.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport2/datasources/
-rw----     2.0 fat      133 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport2/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     8866 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport2/layout.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1247 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport2/styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      274 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport3/content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      671 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport3/datadefinition.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport3/datasources/
-rw----     2.0 fat      133 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport3/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     6988 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport3/layout.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1247 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport3/styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      274 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport4/content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      669 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport4/datadefinition.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport4/datasources/
-rw----     2.0 fat      133 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport4/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     6976 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport4/layout.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1247 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport4/styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      274 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport5/content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      781 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport5/datadefinition.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport5/datasources/
-rw----     2.0 fat      133 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport5/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     9053 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport5/layout.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     1247 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 subreport5/styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      123 bl defN 17-Feb-01 09:15 translations.properties
50 files, 203465 bytes uncompressed, 26285 bytes compressed:  87.1%
```

*My generated report file:*

```
Archive:  de_kpi2.prpt
Zip file size: 31583 bytes, number of entries: 44
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      133 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport2/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     8831 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport2/layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      776 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport2/datadefinition.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     1247 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport2/styles.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      274 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport2/content.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      133 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport3/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     6988 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport3/layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      671 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport3/datadefinition.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     1247 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport3/styles.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      274 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport3/content.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     5262 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 META-INF/manifest.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      133 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     6987 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport/layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      666 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport/datadefinition.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     1247 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport/styles.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      274 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport/content.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      133 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport4/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     6976 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport4/layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      669 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport4/datadefinition.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     1247 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport4/styles.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      274 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport4/content.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      133 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport1/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     6992 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport1/layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      664 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport1/datadefinition.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     1247 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport1/styles.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      274 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport1/content.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      133 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport5/datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     9018 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport5/layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      781 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport5/datadefinition.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     1247 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport5/styles.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      274 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 subreport5/content.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     6623 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 datasources/inline-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx    26649 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 datasources/scriptable-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      266 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 datasources/compound-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     1226 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 datasources/sql-ds.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      733 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 meta.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx    69804 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 layout.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx    26467 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 datadefinition.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx     4781 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 styles.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      436 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 settings.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      274 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 content.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx       41 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 mimetype
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      673 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 dataschema.xml
-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      123 b- defN 17-Apr-14 23:09 translations.properties
44 files, 203301 bytes uncompressed, 26179 bytes compressed:  87.1%
```

I have checked what those differences mean, but I am not certain with all of them. However I have no idea how to fix / change those differences and if they are the cause of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should read pentaho doc [here](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0L0/130/0C0). Pentaho uses properties files for i18 and it works quite fine. I think that if you make your reports with localization in mind you should be able to apply the same process you have now with slight changes and without unpacking .prpt.